# How can I access a website which only allows Internet Explorer users to view it?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer

My university website is designed in such a way that just users with Internet Explorer can use it and if you try to access it through other browsers(like: chrome or firefox) it wont allow;

Is there any way that I can use that websites with other browsers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change the user-agent of your browser (sent w/ the HTTP headers of your web requests) to a compatible browser.

If you use **Firefox**, you can get the [User Agent Switcher extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/).

If you use **Chome**, you can get the [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg).

---

Alternatively, you can also get a plugin to integrate Internet Explorer in the browser of your choice (such as [IE Tab for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/ie-tab/), or [IE Tab for Chrome](https://chrome.google.co/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en)).

Comment: tnx for your answer.