# Can anyone mimic, spoof or fake Internet Explorer for this website?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, user-agent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [website just allow Internet Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/543536/website-just-allow-internet-explorer)

Sorry guys, I don't want to ask a question twice([website-just-allow-internet-explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/543536/website-just-allow-internet-explorer)), but I did my best without any success;

The problem as I mentioned on the other post is that my university website just allow access through Internet Explorer; which means that nobody with any other browser(like: chrome, firefox, ...) can access it;(by access I mean inserting the right credentials and entering the system)

So as one of the guys answered, I used **User Agent Switcher** extension for **Google chrome**; 3 of them; but none of them worked;(for popular sites like yahoo or facebook yes but **my university website sill can recognize the real browser and denies access**)

**So how can I access it through Google Chrome?**

> guys this is not a joke or a game, I really need to know how I can do this; tnx in advance;

This the website of my university: [Educational Management System](http://sama.azaruniv.edu/)
[image]

**for testing:**

1.don't change the value of the first combobox;

2.enter random numbers for next two text fields;

3.correct captcha for the third text field;

**if the website still detects Google Chrome it will show this message:**
[image]

**if you became successful (of course your credentials are still wrong but you passed the recognition) you will see something like this:**
[image]

Comment: Besides a UA Switcher, did you even try IE Tab for Chrome as directed in the solution?

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions, it will only annoy people who would otherwise want to help you. Just update your original question with the extra information you have added here and un-accept the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried an IE Tab for Chrome?

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Comment: This will be the *only* way. The website makes use of IE-specific javascript for basic functionality (ajax requests), and it will not run inside of webkit (Chrome's renderer).

Comment: @DarthAndroid, FYI I just tried this using IE Tab for Firefox, and it did not work.

Comment: @wiki, did this actually work for you?

Comment: IE Tab Multi (Enhance) did the job;
tnx a lot;